# Alert Controller stacked in nested condition

Tags: javascript

I am doing a comparison to validate QR Code using the data retrieved from Firestore. It should navigate to another page if the condition is satisfied. Based on my code, it kept on returning ***'Invalid Code'*** and ***multiple stacked alerts*** even if the condition is true. Is there a simpler solution to compare? I just can't quite figure it out. Here's my code.

```
scan() {
    this.scanner.scan().then((data) => {
        let qrcode = data.text.length;

        this.afs.firestore.collection('item1')
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                snapshot.docs.forEach(doc1 => {

                    var data1 = doc1.data();
                    var itemName = data1.itemname;
                    var itemID = data1.itemid;

                    this.afs.firestore.collection('item2')
                        .get()
                        .then((snapshot) => {
                            snapshot.docs.forEach(doc2 => {

                                var data2 = doc2.data();
                                var itemName2 = data2.itemname2;
                                var itemID2 = data2.itemid2;
                                var description = data2.description;


                                if (doc1.exists) {
                                    if (qrcode == 10 && itemName == itemName2 && itemID == itemID2) {
                                        this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/nextPage');
                                    } else {
                                        return this.presentAlert('Error', 'Invalid Code')
                                    }
                                } else if (description == null) {
                                    return this.presentAlert('Error', 'Nothing found')

                                } else {
                                    return this.presentAlert('Error', 'QR Not Found')
                                }
                            })
                        })
                })
            })
    }, (err) => {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue is because you have 2 nested "forEach" cycles and even is you routine has a valid condition there isn't a return statement and your cycles never been stopped(using break)

I adjusted your code to break the cycles

```
scan() {
    this.scanner.scan().then((data) => {
        let qrcode = data.text.length;

        this.afs.firestore.collection('item1')
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                snapshot.docs.forEach(doc1 => {

                    var data1 = doc1.data();
                    var itemName = data1.itemname;
                    var itemID = data1.itemid;

                    var check = this.afs.firestore.collection('item2')
                        . get()
                        .then((snapshot) => {
                            snapshot.docs.forEach(doc2 => {
                                var data2 = doc2.data();
                                var itemName2 = data2.itemname2;
                                var itemID2 = data2.itemid2;
                                var description = data2.description;
                                if (doc1.exists) {
                                    if (qrcode == 10 && itemName == itemName2 && itemID == itemID2) {
                                        return true
                                    } else {
                                        return this.presentAlert('Error', 'Invalid Code')
                                    }
                                } else if (description == null) {
                                    return this.presentAlert('Error', 'Nothing found')

                                } else {
                                    return this.presentAlert('Error', 'QR Not Found')
                                }
                            })
                        })
                    if (check){
                        this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/nextPage');
                        break
                    }else{
                        return check
                    }

                })
            })
    }, (err) => {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
    })
}
```